# How to write " moving on" in traditional Chinese?

Tags: translation, traditional-characters

I'm getting a tattoo in Chinese and I have everything already I'm just missing the "moving on" part. How should I translate it?

Comment: Moving on is the same as continue, so use "继续".

Comment: I'm afraid that you need to provide more details. There is no such single Chinese Word can express 'move on' as far as I know.

Comment: What's the rest of the tattoo? Some context should be provided.

Comment: 勇往直前 - moving forward with courage, if that's what you're looking for indeed.  While the direct translation of moving on is 继续, i bet i'll laugh if I see it, and you don't want that especially as a tatoo

Comment: enter "move on" into jukuu and get 100 example sentences, e.g. 8.  Don't halt here; move on, move on!
 不要停留在这里,往前走,往前走! and use editors to change to traditional characters

Answer (score 1):

"Moving on" can translate some Chinese idioms, such as 堅持不懈,一往無前,堅持到底,奮勇向前, these are traditional Chinese. These idioms mean " always move forward bravely" 勇敢地一直向前进.

Hope this answer can help you.

Answer (score -1):

向着胜利勇敢前进。An inspireing phrase from the song of the Youth Pioneer Group, "Marching bravely towards victory."

Comment: Hi I wasn't the one who downvoted, but could you please explain the sentence a bit more in depth?

Comment: @Alenanno I think what Danny means is '勇往直前', which is a phase to describe moving forward with courage, if that's what you're looking for